# Getting error java uses or overrides a deprecated API with contacts_service package in flutter

Tags: java, android, flutter, mobile

I have setup **contacts_service: ^0.4.6** plugin in my project and added below permissions in androidmanifest.xml file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />  
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
```

Added it's function in my code file but getting below error in console at the time of compiling:

```
... java uses or overrides a deprecated API
```

Please suggest me what is the issue and how can we solve it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution:

Open **app/build.gradle**, increase the **minSdkVersion**:

Change this:

```
minSdkVersion 16
```

into this:

```
minSdkVersion 23
```

And this solved my issue. I hope, this will also help you. Thanks.